# Find all integrable functions $f$ satisfying for every $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ , $\left|\int_I f(t)dt\right|\leq (m(I))^2$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, real-numbers

> Find all integrable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
> that for every measurable set $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$,
>
> $\left|\int_I f(t)dt\right|\leq (m(I))^2$

where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I have tried to do it by case, when $m(I)<1$ and when $m(I)\geq 1$; however, I have not progressed much. Any help is appreciate it.

Comment: You did not say what $m$ is.  Perhaps it is Lebesgue measure?  Do you really assume this for all $I \subseteq \mathbb R$, and not just for (say) meaurable sets?  Or for intervals?

Comment: Yes, it is measurable sets. I will edit the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: how would you use it?

Answer (score 1):

By decomposing an interval $I$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length, and summing the given inequality on them, you obtain that $|\int_I f| \le m(I)^2/n \;$ so $\int_I f=0$. From this it follows (e.g. by differentiating the integral $\int_0^x f$) that $f=0$ a.e.